# Can't resolve all parameters for LocationTracker

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic2, location, ionic3

i'm trying to follow this sample code by Josh Morony, 
but I can't seem to find how to fix this.

I get an Error from console, it's display on webrowser, and even on device.

I have added the plugins:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/geolocation
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/background-geolocation
```

Here is the error message

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for LocationTracker: ([object Object], [object Object], [object Object], ?).at syntaxError (file:///android_asset/www/build/vendor.js:79310:34)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (file:///android_asset/www/build/vendor.js:92647:35)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (file:///android_asset/www/build/vendor.js:92515:26)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getInjectableMetadata (file:///android_asset/www/build/vendor.js:92501:21)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getProviderMetadata (file:///android_asset/www/build/vendor.js:92791:40)
    at file:///android_asset/www/build/vendor.js:92720:49
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata (file:///android_asset/www/build/vendor.js:92681:19)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (file:///android_asset/www/build/vendor.js:92336:50)
    at JitCompiler._loadModules (file:///android_asset/www/build/vendor.js:103400:66)
```

pages/home/home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LocationTracker } from '../../providers/location-tracker/location-tracker';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public locationTracker: LocationTracker) {

    this.startTracking();
  }

  startTracking(){
    this.locationTracker.startTracking();
  }

  stopTracking(){
    this.locationTracker.stopTracking();
  }
}
```

/pages/home/home.html

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-label>Current Latitude: {{locationTracker.lat}</ion-label>
  <ion-label>Current Longitude: {{locationTracker.lng}}</ion-label>
</ion-content>
```

/providers/location-tracker/location-tracker.ts

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { BackgroundGeolocation } from '@ionic-native/background-geolocation';
import { Geolocation, Geoposition } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';

@Injectable()
export class LocationTracker {

  public watch: any;    
  public lat: number = 0;
  public lng: number = 0;

  constructor(public zone: NgZone, public backgroundGeolocation: BackgroundGeolocation, public geolocation: Geolocation, public geoposition: Geoposition) {

  }

  startTracking() {

    // Background Tracking

    let config = {
      desiredAccuracy: 0,
      stationaryRadius: 20,
      distanceFilter: 10, 
      debug: true,
      interval: 2000 
    };

    this.backgroundGeolocation.configure(config).subscribe((location) => {

      console.log('BackgroundGeolocation:  ' + location.latitude + ',' + location.longitude);

      // Run update inside of Angular's zone
      this.zone.run(() => {
        this.lat = location.latitude;
        this.lng = location.longitude;
      });

    }, (err) => {

      console.log(err);

    });

    // Turn ON the background-geolocation system.
    this.backgroundGeolocation.start();


    // Foreground Tracking

    let options = {
      frequency: 3000, 
      enableHighAccuracy: true
    };

    this.watch = this.geolocation.watchPosition(options).filter((p: any) => p.code === undefined).subscribe((position: Geoposition) => {

      console.log(position);

      // Run update inside of Angular's zone
      this.zone.run(() => {
        this.lat = position.coords.latitude;
        this.lng = position.coords.longitude;
      });

    });
  }

  stopTracking() {
   console.log('stopTracking');

    this.backgroundGeolocation.finish();
    this.watch.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

app/app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { LocationTracker } from '../providers/location-tracker/location-tracker';
import { BackgroundGeolocation } from '@ionic-native/background-geolocation';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    HttpModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
    LocationTracker,
    BackgroundGeolocation,
    Geolocation
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: It can be Ionic 2 or 3, but it cannot be both :) in the tags

Comment: Hi onetwo12,
are you referring to the tagging?

Comment: I see what you mean. I'm assuming this error could be in both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you taje a look at the error, it says that the fourth parameter couldn't be injected

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for LocationTracker: ([object Object], [object Object], [object Object], ?)
```

Looking at your code from the Injectable

```
constructor(public zone: NgZone,
            public backgroundGeolocation: BackgroundGeolocation,
            public geolocation: Geolocation,
            public geoposition: Geoposition) {
}
```

the fourth is this Geoposition, which is seems you are not 'providing' in the NgModule.

So, as long as you are not using this 'geoposition' instance/object, you can simply remove it from the constructor:

```
constructor(public zone: NgZone,
            public backgroundGeolocation: BackgroundGeolocation,
            public geolocation: Geolocation) {
}
```

Comment: Nice.. Your explanation helped me comprehend how to read the errors a bit better...

Comment: Many thanks! I see it now. I'll make this the answer once I have tested it by tomorrow.

Comment: You explained it so well and precise.

Comment: You are correct Christian. 
You found the error. 
However, the fix is to remove instead the geoposition from the constructor since it is not needed, and it doesn't need to be 'provided' in the NgModule. 

Please add it up to your answer and I'll accept it as the correct one. 
Thank you so much.

Comment: Hello @ChristianBenseler! It works because "Geoposition" are not used in the page. But, if it will be used and the presence in the constructor is required?